# Disable scrollbar thumb drag event, keep all other scroll events enabled - javascript, html

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, scroll, scrollbar

I want to disable scroll-bar dragging while keeping all other means of capturing scroll events enabled.

A means of capturing a mousedown event on the scrollbar would also suffice (most text on that topic points to not possible). I do not want to use any external libraries to solve the issue. Any other means of coming to a solution to the problem described below are welcome.

The solution only has to work in current versions of Google Chrome.

```
    document.getElementById('mainTable').parentNode.addEventListener("scroll",function(e){
        ...

        //Other code logic and syntax omitted

        ...
        //Logic for deriving if scrolling up or down is accomplished by comparing
        //the previously recorded .scrollTop value to the current value of the div 
        //containing the table 'mainTable' of datapoints
        if(scrollDownEvent){
           document.getElementById("mainTable").parentNode.scrollTo(0,.75*totHeight);
        }else if(scrollUpEvent){
           document.getElementById("mainTable").parentNode.scrollTo(0,.25*totHeight);
        }else{

        }
    }
```

**Background**
Some really quick background information. I have several million data points with a large set of data for each point.

I load 200 data points into the html, into a table/tr/td set-up. I cache 400 data points into a javascript array of objects (roughly 100 above and below at any given point in time).

When the user scrolls down, if the edge of the datapoints being displayed comes near the edge of the cached data points, more points are loaded into the cache from the harddrive (via html5 file-system api). Depending on how far down the scroll event attributes state were scrolled defines how many data points are removed from the opposing end of the table and new data points are loaded into the target edge of the table. after handling the scroll event I then scroll to either 25% of the height of the table or 75% of the table.

**The Problem** I am running into is the scroll event appears to be fired differently with scrollbar drags than with other means of scroll events. I am capturing a scroll-bar drag event as a scroll event, but if I drag the scrollbar all the way to the bottom (my code works if I do not drag it all the way down), it'll sometimes appear to somehow overwrite my javascript code to scroll back up - thus resulting in an inability to scroll down farther and fire off anymore scroll events.

I have no issues with scroll events captured from:

- mouse wheel move
- mouse clicks on the up/down arrows
- mouse clicks on the upper/lower region relative to the scrollbar
- mouse downs on the upper/lower regions relative to the scrollbar.
- mouse downs on the up/down arrow buttons
- key down on keyboard up/down arrows

Comment: i'd recommend to make own scroll

Comment: It's starting to look like that may be my best bet, thank you for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not end up making my own scrollbar, I didn't use any external scrollbar libraries either. I resolved the issue by calculating positions of the scrollbar thumb and tracking the mouse position, handling the upper/lower bounds of the scroller that were causing the scroller to lock-up.

**Mouse-over scroll-bar thumb code**

I added mousemove events to several elements. I calculated the physical location and width of the scrollbar. When the mouse moved in those locations I handled mouseover events appropriately. I was also able to calculate the height of the thumbar itself by looking at mainTable's parent height and comparing it to mainTable's height. I was able to calculate the thumbar's location by looking at the scrollTop.

```
document.getElementById("mainTable").parentNode.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
    var mainTab = document.getElementById("mainTable");
    if(mainTab.offsetWidth <= e.offsetX){
        var scrollbarHeight = mainTab.parentNode.offsetHeight - 36; //36 =height of up and down arrows
        var scrollbarThumbHeight = (scrollbarHeight/mainTab.offsetHeight)*scrollbarHeight;
        var childScrollTop = mainTab.parentNode.scrollTop
        var relativeThumbPosition = (childScrollTop/mainTab.offsetHeight) + 18; // 18=height of up arrow
        if(e.offsetY >= relativeThumbPosition && e.offsetY <= relativeThumbPosition+scrollbarThumbHeight){
            console.log("mouse-move thumbar:\t" + e.which);
            //execute specific mouse over code here
        }else{
            //execute any non-mouse over specific code here
        }
    }
})
```

## The following method ultimately fixed my problem

**Scrollbar thumb stuck at bottom or top - handling**
*This is within a `mousemove` event Listener on the document body*

There is probably a better way to do this one, by say adding and removing the event listener (only doing it when it is needed) However, I added the listener and checked always - again in the future I'll probably modify this so it is more efficient. I check to see if the scroll position is locked at the top or the bottom of the scrollbar track. If it is, I handle the infinite scrollbar appropriately.

```
var mainTab = document.getElementById("mainTable");
if(mainTab.parentNode.scrollTop == 0){
    if(cnTable.buffStart != 0){
        upEvent(27);
    }else if (cnTable.tableStart != 0){
        upEvent(27);
    }
}else if(mainTab.parentNode.scrollTop + mainTab.parentNode.offsetHeight >= totHeight ){
    if(cnTable.buffStop < cnDAO.currentIndexes.length -1){
        downEvent(27);
    }else if (cnTable.tableStop < cnTable.buffer.length-1){
        downEvent(27);
    }
}
```

**Lastly, code for setting the scroll position found within the `upEvent` and `downEvent`**

*The following code is almost identical to the code in question above*

As mentioned above I handled the position, the following code is what I used to change the position, there is a lot more code that went into calculating the position, but I decided to only show the generic case (not all of my rows are all the same height so I had to adjust appropriately in the code not shown in the up and down events)

```
var totHeight = document.getElementById("mainTable").offsetHeight -1;
document.getElementById("mainTable").parentNode.scrollTo(0,.24*totHeight);
```

AND

```
var totHeight = document.getElementById("mainTable").offsetHeight -1;
document.getElementById("mainTable").parentNode.scrollTo(0,.76*totHeight);
```